Create a back button that skips specific page
I need to add a "Back" link that goes back 1 page (history.go(-1)) UNLESS the previous page is a specific URL. In that case, I want the link to go back 3 pages (history.go(-3)).
I thought this would be simple by using either document.referrer in JS or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in PHP, but in both methods, the referring url is always blank, so obviously that won't work.
The referring url that I want to skip would contain the following parameter at the end: ?um_action=edit
So for example, a user might take this path:

mysite.com/directory
mysite.com/member/profile
mysite.com/member/profile/?um_action=edit
mysite.com/member/profile

If you are on step 1, 2 or 3, the back link would take you back to the previous page. But if you are on step 4, I want the back link to jump back to step 1.
How can I achieve this? This is a wordpress site, and there is an action I can hook into that runs on step 3 above when the profile is saved. Could I use this somehow?
Thank you!

Please don't break people's expectation of how the back button works.

It's going to be specific and say "Back to Directory" so I think people will understand it. Their browser back button will continue to work normally. It was a specific user request to get them back to the directory faster after editing a profile.

Just make that a normal navigation "forward" action? I.e. just make "back to directory" a normal link. No need for back button shenanigans.

Well it's tricky because the user may have filtered the directory before arriving on a profile, so they want to literally go back to where they were, rather than a clean link to the unfiltered directory page.

But that's presumably what you have sessions for: your backend knows what link it should be generating based on knowing what your user's been filtering for.

Ok, thank you. I guess that's the solution I need help with.

I was recently on a fairly well-known enterprise commerce platform and they had a "back to something" feature, too. I'm one of those people that like to open certain links in a new tab (like if I need to edit multiple objects) and the "back" button, which was in JavaScript, was completely worthless. So I'm just chiming in with everyone else, don't fight this one.

1 You see blank result of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] maybe because you're typing by hand in url, if you click on link with ?um_action=edit, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should work correctly.
2 How to create a backlink with steps.
You can do it just by using SESSIONS. You need to save all your urls HTTP_REFERER in sessions and you can go back to step 1. Here is an example of how this can be done. Add code to functions.php into template.
To the top of functions.php
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}

Backlink script code (add to bottom into file functions.php)
add_shortcode( 'bl', 'backlink');

function backlink() {


$prevurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$thisurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['steps'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['steps'] = array();
    $steps = $_SESSION['steps'];
} else if (!strstr($prevurl, $thisurl)) {
    array_push($_SESSION['steps'], $prevurl );
    $steps = $_SESSION['steps'];
} else {
    $steps = $_SESSION['steps'];
}



if (strstr($prevurl, $thisurl))  {
$arraycount = count($steps);
$getkey = $arraycount - 1;
$backlink = $_SESSION['steps'][$getkey];
} else if (strstr($prevurl, '?um_action=edit')) {
$arraycount = count($steps);
$getkey = $arraycount - 3;
$backlink = $_SESSION['steps'][$getkey];
} else if (!strstr($prevurl, '?um_action=edit') AND !strstr($thisurl, '?um_action=edit')) {
$backlink = $prevurl;
} else if (strstr($thisurl, '?um_action=edit')) {
$arraycount = count($steps);
$getkey = $arraycount - 1;
$backlink = $_SESSION['steps'][$getkey];
}


echo "<a href='$backlink'>BACK LINK</a>";

}

Add the generated shortcode to the pages you need in Admin panel.
[bl]
